# WP7 Virtualizing WrapPanel

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use a WrapPanel in my WP7 app, so I used the wrappanel contained in [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034).
The problem with this wrappanel is that it doesnt support UI virtualization.

Can you give some directions on how to implement UI virtualization for a WrapPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind explaining your requirement around wrap panel. Because for most of the situations you might be able to make with a combination of VirtualizedStackPanel vertically and fixed items inside each row. I have done this way in many apps, because making a wrap panel virtualizing is hard compared to what easy performance and flexibility I can get from this small work around. Yes orientation can easily trigger for 'number of items per row' change to compensate the width changes.

Comment: Indeed it is a good idea. I need 3 or 4 items per row, so I can create a collection to bind to a ListBox where each ListItem contains 3-4 of my items.

Comment: I do this - although you need to handle changes in orientation to put a different number of items per row.

Comment: @JobiJoy Your solution is OK, I have 3 items per row. So how can I select an item. Listbox only allow to click a row, not a single item ??