# Virtualizing WrapPanel for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, wrappanel, virtualizingstackpanel

I need to create a wrap panel with my facebook friends, meaning the itemcount is over 400, and it takes 5-10 seconds for all the items to load.

```
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

This code would be good, but it puts all the elements in 1 Row ...:

```
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Any ideas how to add item wraping to VirtualizingStackPanel or how to add Virtualizing to a WrapPanel:

Comment: There is a [commercial](http://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/WPF_SL/virtualizingwrappanel_wpf_sl.htm) version of a VirtualizingWrapPanel available. But I can't vouch for it's quality, since I've never used it.

Comment: There exists a project which does this. See [this link](http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @CodeNaked Yes I've found that commercial version myself though I would prefer a free version.

Comment: @abhinav I tried that, that is for WPF, and there are lots of exceptions when trying to import to WP7

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 Virtualizing WrapPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046810/wp7-virtualizing-wrappanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used it by creating a simple listbox, with each element containing a stackpanel with 4 images. cheers

Comment: From here: http://debugmode.net/2011/08/20/nested-listbox-binding-in-silverlight-and-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 0):

Well, the whole point with the WrapPanel is that it adjusts to the size of the content. So it needs to render all items to determind the size.

So you're pretty much out of luck, when it comes to virtualizing that part. However, if it's 400 images you're loading, you could use the [LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx) to improve the loading speed drastically.

You can find a mirror of the [LowProfileImageLoader source code on my GitHub](https://github.com/Windcape/GOTOcon/blob/master/GotoCon/Assets/LowProfileImageLoader.cs).

Comment: Than what about wrapping the items in VirtualizingStackPanel? Is there a workaround that?