# VirtualizingWrapPanel on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Where can i find virtualizing WrapPanel for Windows Phone or way to implement it successfully, In current situation when there are more than 100 images the page gets hang. But using VirtualizingStackPanel it works fine. I also want to know if there is any other way to do the same.

Comment: Take a look at the answer on here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978933/virtualizing-wrappanel-for-wp7

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here => http://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/WPF_SL/virtualizingwrappanel_wpf_sl.htm