# Is it possible to load ListboxItems of type Image as user scrolls the content using a WrapPanel as the PanelTemplate?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone 7 that populates a `WrapPanel` with a list of objects retrieved from an `ObservableCollection<Photo>`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Photo}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding File}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="150" ItemWidth="150" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

It's working how it's supposed to work (in the means that it's loading all the images), but I'm having some performance issues since `WrapPanel : Panel`. So it doesn't virtualize any data, loading all the `Image` objects of the `ListBox`, even the ones that the user can't see.

This approach is OK when `ObservableCollection<Photo>.Count <= 30` but as the `Collection` gets bigger and bigger things start to get slow.

> *Since the user can have up to 1000 images, it's simply not going to work this way. Even though I'm binding Thumbnails to display the Image object.*

I've tried to use [David Anson's LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx) to create Images off the UI thread. And to bind the Images as the user scrolls the `ListBox`. But it doesn't work since it's expecting an `UriSource` and I'm actually binding a `BitmapImage` to the `Image.Source`, because the images are beeing loaded from `IsolatedStorage`.

```
public class Photo : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    ...
    ...

    public BitmapImage File
    {
        get
        {
            // Thumbnail
            string filePath = Path.Combine("Images", FileName);

            byte[] data;

            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    data = new byte[isfs.Length];

                    isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    isfs.Close();
                }
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

            bi.SetSource(ms);

            return bi;
        }
    }
}
```

**Can anyone help me in this task of making the content (photos) load as the user sees it? Is there anything such as a `VirtualizingWrapPanel` or `WrapPanel : VirtualizingPanel`?**

Thanks. If any code snippet is needed feel free to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 Virtualizing WrapPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046810/wp7-virtualizing-wrappanel)

Comment: There is also a commercial [Virtualizing Wrap Panel](http://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/WPF_SL/virtualizingwrappanel_wpf_sl.htm)

Comment: @nemesv i did see this question but the answers didn't solved my problem, so I'm asking not only about VirtualizedWrapPanel, but actually any workaround to make the list smooth. I've also included some code snippet to try to make my question as clear as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the images to memory from the storage when the user scrolls will make your UI jittery especially when the user tries to scroll or see more elements very quickly.
But, if you have all the images in memory and then would like to bind the images to the listbox on scrolling, you could use the [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx). A wrap panel would need to know the size of the images to display correctly. A workaround is possible if you know the size of the images and if they're all the same.

You could customize the `VirtualizingStackPanel` and position the images in rows like the way they would in a wrappanel, or any other way you like.

Hope that helps.

Although, 
I am not sure if this will solve the problem when you have 1000 heavy images. But it is worth a try, if you haven't done so.

EDIT: [This article](http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Improving-ListBox-Performance-in-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7-Data-Virtualization.aspx) might help.

Comment: do you know how I can customize a VirtualizingStackPanel to show 3 items per row? Since I know the items width is always 150px? could you give me some code snippet? I'm at work now and as soon as I get home I'll try to make my own customization. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a wrap panel from a virtualized listbox.
[Here](http://debugmode.net/2011/08/20/nested-listbox-binding-in-silverlight-and-windows-phone-7/) is a link how to do it. it works pretty good, but it has 1 problem... it will have a tilt effect on a whole line instead of an item... I'm currently investigating that problem.