# WP7 toolkit wrappanel virtualization

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, wrappanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WP7 Virtualizing WrapPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046810/wp7-virtualizing-wrappanel)

I am using wrappanel control in [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) to display 100+ images. But the wrappanel does not support UI virtualization (my app loads all images very slowly).

Can anyone tell me how to implement UI virtualization for a WrapPanel?